# Do compilers other than MSVC have a version of MSVC's SAL?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have been looking into intrinsic functions and came across SAL, which stands for Microsoft [Source-code Annotation Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/understanding-sal?view=msvc-170). I was wondering if other compilers had the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A feature-for-feature equivalent does not exist, but there are similar checks that can be enabled in clang and/or gcc via some attributes.

Some examples:

- [clang Source Annotations](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html)
- some [GCC attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html): `format` and `format_arg` are similar to SAL's `_Printf_format_string_`.

Some of these will be picked up by static code analyzers such as `clang-tidy`, while others can generate compile-time warnings.

Note that there is no perfect overlap between these two. That is, some checks that are available via SAL will not be available with clang/gcc annotations, while some checks which are available to clang/gcc have no SAL equivalent.